# Does "The Stress of Her Regard" have sparkly-skinned vampires?

Tags: vampire

Does *The Stress of Her Regard* have sparkly-skinned vampires? The other information I'd easily believe, and I know both vampires are made of stony materials, but do the ones in *The Stress of Her Regard*, **sparkle**?

Preferably with a quote to confirm...

From TVTropes: [OlderThanTheyThink/Literature](https://tvtropes.org/OlderThanTheyThink/Literature):

> ** Vampires whose bodies are largely composed of sparkly minerals? Check. Abusive vampire/human love affairs with nonstop bed-breaking sex? Check. Improvised Caesarean section on a human who's impregnated with an unprecedented vampire offspring? Check ... **if** it's [The Stress of Her Regard](https://tvtropes.org/Literature/TheStressOfHerRegard) (1989) by Tim Powers, and not [Twilight](https://tvtropes.org/Literature/Twilight).

Comment: They are kind of sparkly, in some forms, and they are definitely made of minerals. The latter two statements look a little more dubious. The human was male, and it was not an offspring exactly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Kind of...

What counts as sparkling? To me it signifies that light refects off of small bits of something in a material, or at least emanates from the same. I don't think this happens with the Nephilim in the book. But they do glow, sometimes.

> Her flesh warmed around him as the hours were achingly chiselled away, and when at last she rose from the bed she was actually glowing faintly, like the bricks lining a smithy's stove.

They have a sort of aura:

> "The thing that attacked us in the Alps glowed with those colors," Crawford said quietly, "just before it petrified."

They also "glitter" when they are in their reptilian form:

> It curled heavily in the air, its metallic-looking scales glittering in the torchlight. Its long snout opened, showing a white brush of teeth, and its glassy eyes swivelled from Byron to Crawford, and then down to where Josephine lay on the stones.

But they don't really sparkle in sunlight like mica, the way Twilight vampires do. They glow with an aura, and when they change into lizards, logically enough, their scales reflect light.